# Query not contain in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have a collection data like this

```
[
  {
    items : [
      {isTrue : false},
      {isTrue : true},
    ]
  },
  {
    items : [
      {isTrue : false},
      {isTrue : false},
    ]
  },
  {
    items : [
      {isTrue : true},
      {isTrue : false},
    ]
  },
  {
    items : [
      {isTrue : true},
      {isTrue : true},
    ]
  },
]
```

I only want to get items that doesnt have isTrue : true
so the data count is 1

anyone have an answer?

Comment: What was you try?

Comment: You have to clarify your question. What you want to do is search all items where the "boolean or conjunction" of all children is "true", which is a little bit more complicated than a "not contain".

Comment: yes @Smutje that is what i want,,, did you know how?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operator

```
db.collection.find({'items': { '$not':  { '$eq': { isTrue: true }}}})
```

Comment: @Lumanyun I don't think so. Perhaps you are doing something wrong